# How to change the color of a button for only a few seconds using angular?

Tags: angularjs, settimeout, ng-class

I want my button to change color when clicked. Also only change it for 3 seconds and then go back to the default color. I have been looking at similar questions postet on stack overflow but whatever I tried it didn't work (don't know why my code isn't working). Also Im not sure how to make it change the color for only 3 seconds.
So far I
1.  $scope.isActive=false;
2. then in the controller, I changed it to true if clicked:

```
$scope.copyText = function(text){
  $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  console.log('clicked in controller');
  Clipboard.copy(text)
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="inner-single" ng-hide="updateInfo">
    <h3>Login Details:</h3>
    <h5 ><span class="categories">Username:</span> {{account.username}}<button 
         ng-click="copyText(account.username)" ng-class="isActive ? 'noColor' : 'hasColor'" >
    Copy</button></h5>    
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-default" ng-click="showForm()">Update Info</button>
```

**CSS**

```
 .copy-button {
  .copy-button.hasColor {
    color:green;
  }
  .copy-button.noColor {
   color: grey; }
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0px, 3px, 0px, 3px;
  margin-left: 5px; }
}
```

For keeping track of the seconds, I would use the setTimeout function, however, not sure how to combine it with angular and changing the color..

Happy about suggestions!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$timeout` here with `3000`(3 sec), and the again preset `isActive` flag over there.

**Code**

```
$scope.copyText = function(text){
  $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  console.log('clicked in controller');
  Clipboard.copy(text);
  //don't forget to add `$timeout` in controller dependency.
  $timeout(function(){
      $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  }, 3000);
}
```

---

It seems like your CSS rules are incorrect, you have to correct them or otherwise put `copy-button` class over `button`

```
.copy-button.hasColor {
  color: green;
}

.copy-button.noColor {
  color: grey;
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zo1vLvym2tWnv03cz7TO?p=preview)

Comment: thank you! But do you know why my code doesn't work for changing the color? Regardless of the time

Comment: To back to original class you have to click it twice,then only it would work

Comment: how can I make the button change to the original class without having to click again? Also, neither changing to original class works nor changing at all (it won't change the color to green at all)

Comment: @javascript2016 per me it should work.. should I create a demo?

Comment: yes that would be great as absolutely nothing works !

Comment: @javascript2016 give me a minute

Comment: @javascript2016 look at the udpated answer

Comment: this doesn't work in my case- maybe I have to also change something in the html?

Comment: You only need to add `copy-button` class on button

Answer (score 1):

better to use `$interval` then timeout in this case

```
 let stuff = $interval(function() {
           do stuff
      }, 100);
  };
```